# Error MergeMappingExcemption failed

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a problem when trying to update`u maps on the server. I needs to add some fields to the map.I count on your help in this matter.

I'm trying to do update the map:

```
curl -XGET http://x.xxx.xx.xx:9200/allek/_mapping/auctions?pretty
{
  "allek" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "auctions" : {
        "_all" : {
          "enabled" : false
        },
        "properties" : {
          "cat" : {
            "type" : "long",
            "store" : true
          },
          "curr" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "index" : "not_analyzed",
            "store" : true
          },
          "end_date" : {
            "type" : "long",
            "store" : true
          },
          "price" : {
            "type" : "long",
            "store" : true
          },
          "start_date" : {
            "type" : "long",
            "store" : true
          },
          "tcat" : {
            "type" : "long",
            "store" : true
          },
          "title" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "store" : true
          },
          "uid" : {
            "type" : "long",
            "store" : true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Ton the map:

```
{
  "_all": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "properties": {
    "cat": {
      "store": true,
      "type": "long",
      "doc_values": true
    },
    "curr": {
      "index": "not_analyzed",
      "store": true,
      "type": "string",
      "doc_values": true
    },
    "end_date": {
      "store": true,
      "type": "long",
      "doc_values": true
    },
    "price": {
      "store": true,
      "type": "long",
      "doc_values": true
    },
    "start_date": {
      "store": true,
      "type": "long",
      "doc_values": true
    },
    "tcat": {
      "store": true,
      "type": "long",
      "doc_values": true
    },
    "title": {
      "store": true,
      "type": "string",
      "fields": {
        "raw": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed",
          "ignore_above": 256,
          "doc_values": true
        }
      }
    },
    "uid": {
      "store": true,
      "type": "long",
      "doc_values": true
    }
  }
}
```

But I get the message:

```
{"error":"MergeMappingException[Merge failed with failures {[mapper [uid] has di
fferent doc_values values, mapper [end_date] has different doc_values values, ma
pper [cat] has different doc_values values, mapper [start_date] has different do
c_values values, mapper [curr] has different doc_values values, mapper [price] h
as different doc_values values, mapper [tcat] has different doc_values values]}]
","status":400}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Is to be able to perform this operation I have to do reindex data and delete the old map and add only the new?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the doc_values defaults to false, when you are setting it to true in your update you create a conflict with the existing mapping.
Your only option is to reindex.